# Как правильно сформулировать ответ?

Tags: грамотная-речь, управление

На ваш исх. № 5 от 29.05.15 о несогласии с возложением материальной ответственности...*

или

На ваш исх. № 5 от 29.05.15 о несогласии возложения материальной ответственности...*

Answer (score 1):

Лучше первый вариант (**о** [вашем] **несогласии** [с тем-то]). Но не может быть "номер о несогласии" - есть *письмо о несогласии*, номер которого такой-то. Поэтому что-то из этого нужно заключить в скобки:

> На ваш исх. № 5 от 29.05.15 (о несогласии с возложением материальной
>   ответственности...)

или:

> На ваше письмо (исх. № 5 от 29.05.15) о несогласии с возложением
>   материальной ответственности...

Если в письме был буквально такой заголовок, его можно привести в кавычках с заглавной буквы.